# Error when connecting to mssql server with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to connect to a Navision database (MSSQL 2008) through PHP.

On my Linux server, I have build FreeDTS and recompiled PHP with the mssql extension.

However, I get the following error:

> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server:

I have copied the code to a Windows server running PHP, and it connects just fine.

**Server info:**

```
OS: Centos 6.2
PHP version: 5.2.17
FreeDTS version: 0.91
```

I have tried to connect to the Mssql server through telnet, and that works fine. So no firewall issues.

Comment: the windows server will use another driver...  can you post the connection method you are using?  sometimes doing a vanilla `$db = mssql_connect('db',uid','pwd');` will give you more information than functions or classful connection method.  Alternatively, try the odbc driver?

Comment: I'm using exactly that connection method. Should I try uninstall FreeTDS and install odbc and recompile PHP?

Comment: unless you get more specific ideas from the group here.  You should be able to install odbc alongside everything else just to try it out.  I found (on windows mind you, and prior to sqlsrv maturity) that odbc performed more reliably than mssql in some cases...  but not related to connection issues.